# Proving the open interval $(0,1)$ is uncountable

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof

I am currently able to prove this statement using the Cantor diagonalisation argument, my question is whether there is another way (more simple or more complex) to prove this statement, without diagonalisation?

Comment: Depends on what you know. Do you know of any other uncountable sets? If so, it is enough to find a bijection between $(0, 1)$ and such a set.

Comment: I don't think that the other way can be simpler. After all, the Cantor diagonalisation argument is beautiful exactly because it is simple. Don't get me wrong, there *may* exist a simpler way. I just doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by showing that there is a bijection between $(0, 1)$ and $\mathbb R$.

Two sets are equivalent (have equal cardinalities) if and only if there exists a bijection between them. $\mathbb R$ is uncountable. So by showing that there exists a bijection from $(0, 1)$ to $\mathbb R$, you thereby show that $(0, 1)$ is uncountable.

However, it is perhaps more common that we first establish the fact that $(0, 1)$ is uncountable (by Cantor's diagonalization argument), and then use the above method (finding a bijection from $(0, 1)$ to $\mathbb R)$ to conclude that $\mathbb R$ itself is uncountable.

Comment: Why does this prove uncountability?

Comment: @user127700 It does if you already know that $\mathbb R$ is uncountable.

Comment: @5xum I know that R is uncountable, but for clarity's sake, how would one prove that R is uncountable?

Comment: It seems that the most common proof that shows that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable is really showing that $(0,1)$ is uncountable due to diagonalization...

Comment: @user127700 Speaking for myself, I know $\mathbb R$ is uncountable because there exist a bijection betwen it and $(0,1)$ and I know that is uncountable because of Cantor...

Comment: @SimonRose That was what I feared, as I did not want to construct a proof based on circular reasoning.

Comment: Is there a way to prove this using nested intervals? It reminds me of something I've seen before, but can't quite put the pieces together!

Answer (score 2):

No one mentioned Baire ?

Suppose for contradiction that $(0,1)$ is countable.

Let $x_n$ be a sequence such that $(0,1)=\{x_n|n\in \mathbb N\}$

Then $(0,1)=\cup_n \{x_n\}$

Each $\{x_n\}$ is a closed, nowhere dense, subset of $(0,1)$ with the usual metric.

Hence, by Baire category theorem, $(0,1)$ is nowhere dense.

This is a contradiction.

Comment: don't you implicitely use the fact that $(0,1)$ is uncountable in this proof? How do you know that it is not nowhere dense?

Comment: @Denis: Because if an open set is nowhere dense, then it is empty. That been said, I don't fully recall the proof that $\Bbb R$ is a Baire space, and it might rely on basic properties of $\Bbb R$ to begin with, one of which may or may not be uncountability.

Comment: Moreover even if it works it's a little bit cheating, because the proof of Baire theorem involves diagonalization.

Comment: @Denis No, I can provide a proof of Baire theorem that doesn't resort to this

Comment: it depends what you called exactly diagonalization, but I think under reasonable definition it cannot be avoided...

Comment: @Denis I'm telling you, that in the scope of metric spaces, I have a proof that resorts to none of that. If you don't believe me, which is mathematically fine, I'll send you a link.

Comment: @G.T.R Then I'm curious to see it

Comment: G.T.R, without saying one way or another, it is often that we base general theorems for metric spaces on properties of $\Bbb R$ which we take for granted after proving them... with diagonalization. So you have to be careful not to resort to circularity here. You can't use the "general theorem" for $\Bbb R$, if the proof of the theorem relies on properties of $\Bbb R$ that you aim to show.

Comment: @AsafKaragila see here http://mathb.in/17086

Comment: @Denis see also here http://mathb.in/17086

Comment: @G.T.R This proof is the same as the one from Wikipedia I looked before making my comment, and it amonts to diagonalization: you assume the existence of an ordered sequence, and use it to gradually build a sequence by induction, such that its limit will have the property you want. Actually this technique is the dual of a normal proof by diagonalization, by complementing the sets you consider, but it is "isomorphic".

Comment: @Denis What do you mean with "you assume the existence of an ordered sequence"

Comment: I mean you start with a sequence $A_n$, and extract a sequence $(x_n,r_n)$, which can be formulated as a diagonalization procedure.

Comment: @Denis: Diluting a sequence by induction is not the same as diagonalizing over something.

Comment: Here, up to taking the complement sets, the principle is to avoid bigger and bigger sets, which amounts to Cantor orginal diagonalization argument. I agree that the line between diagonalization and not-diagonalization is somewhat blurry. Anyway @AsafKaragila you gave a nice answer of this question on the other thread using order theory, thereby showing that diagonalisation is indeed avoidable.

Comment: @Denis: And as one of the comments to my answer there pointed out, one can argue that the back-and-forth process in which we prove that every two dense linear orders without endpoints are isomorphic is some sort of diagonalization. But I disagree, because as you say, the exact definition of a diagonalization is blurry, and it seem that by insisting enough, any definition by an inductive process which only terminates after $\omega$ steps can be considered diagonalization.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by showin that $2^{\mathbb N}$ is uncoutable quite easily, using the general proof that there is no bijection between $E$ and $2^E$ for any set $E$.
This is because if such a bijection would exist, the set $M=\{x\in E| x\notin f(x)\}$ could have no antecedent $m$ by $f$, because both $m\in M$ and $m\notin M$ lead to a contradiction.

Then, there is an easy injection $2^{\mathbb N}\to (0,1)$, showing that $(0,1)$ is also uncountable: associate to a set $X\subseteq N$ the number whose $i^{th}$ digit is for instance $2$ if $i\in X$ and $5$ otherwise (to avoid reaching $0$ and $1$).

Comment: In a way, this  is still using cantor's diagonalization argument when you construct $M$...

Comment: yes, but I find the subset version easier. Bottomline, if you don't already know that some set is uncountable, you need some kind of diagonalization argument to show that there is one.

Comment: I don't agree, I think versions without diagonalization are possible, as G.T.R. showed.

Comment: the answer of G.T.R also contains diagonalization, hidden in the proof of Baire theorem.